# How to convert LocalDateTime to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` format

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

I'm trying to parse the String in format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` into `LocalDateTime` and if day is `sunday` or `saturday` i want to change date to `monday` and return in same format, i know i can add days by using `plusDays`

```
String str = "2018-09-22T12:30:10Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime.plusDays(2));  //2018-09-24T12:30:10
```

But i want to return in format `2018-09-24T12:30:10Z`

Comment: Your question seems to contradict itself. You first say you want to return the date in the same format you read it in, then you end by saying you want to return the date in a completely different format. You also say you want to replace the day, but your code doesn't show you doing this, so are you asking two questions in one? Or is there only one question and the other "want" is not important?

Comment: Your input string is in UTC. Do you want to check for Saturday or Sunday in your own time zone or in UTC? It’s never the same day in all time zones.

Comment: yes i want to check in UTC? all my systems are in UTC timezone probably it will take default from system right ?

Comment: Sorry but is your question (1) how to print result of `dateTime.plusDays(2)` in form `2018-09-24T12:30:10Z`, or (2) how to check if day of week of `dateTime` is Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: i want to return in this format `2018-09-24T12:30:10Z`, but i got bunch of answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    String str = "2018-09-22T12:30:10Z";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(str);
    DayOfWeek dow = dateTime.getDayOfWeek();
    if (dow.equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) || dow.equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) {
        dateTime = dateTime.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    }
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output from this snippet was:

> 2018-09-24T12:30:10Z

It takes the date from the string, in this case September 22, and since it was a Saturday, it does make the adjustment to the following Monday. It doesn’t use your JVM’s time zone setting.

Your string is in ISO 8601 format, the standard format that the classes from java.time parse and produce as their default, so there is no need for specifying the format through any `DateTimeFormatter`. The `Z` in the string denotes UTC (in other words, offset 0 from UTC), so parse it as an offset and into an `OffsetDateTime` rather than a `LocalDateTime` to keep all information from the string. This also makes it easy to return the same format.

If you need to return a `String`, use `dateTime.toString()`.

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

Use `Instant`, not `LocalDateTime`.

```
Instant                                                // Represent a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).
.parse( "2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z" )             // Parse text in standard ISO 8601 format where the `Z` on the end means UTC.
.truncatedTo( java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS )  // Lop off any fractional second.
.plus(                                                 // Date-time math.
    Duration.ofDays( 2 )                               // Represent a span-of-time not attached to the timeline.
)                                                      // Returns another `Instant` object rather than altering the original.
.toString()                                            // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-01-25T01:23:45Z

## ISO 8601

> parse the String in format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" into LocalDateTime

You cannot. Or should not use `LocalDateTime` for this purpose.

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), and is pronounced “Zulu”. You should never ignore this character, as you seem to be intending by the use of single-quote marks around it.

### `Instant`

Parse such a string as a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z" ) ;
```

### `LocalDateTime`

The `LocalDateTime` class cannot represent a moment. It purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. This class represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the various time zones currently in use around the globe.

### `OffsetDateTime`

To communicate with a database via JDBC, use `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

To see the moment of that `Instant` through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Weekend

To test for the weekend, use the `DayOfWeek` enum in an `EnumSet`.

```
Set< DayOfWeek > weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) ;
```

For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day, while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec. So adjust your `Instant` into the time zone appropriate to your business problem, as shown above.

Compare by extracting a `DayOfWeek` enum object from your `ZonedDateTime`.

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

Compare to see if it is a weekend or weekday.

```
ZonedDateTime target = zdt ;  // Initialize.
if( weekend.contains( dow ) ) {
    target = zdt.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ; // Move from one day to another.
}
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
String str = "2018-09-22T12:30:10Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime.plusDays(2).format(formatter));
```

output:

> 2018-09-24T12:30:10Z

Comment: Missing test for *"if day is sunday or saturday"*

Comment: it is logic for OP!! not me. and just display how display it in expected format that OP wants to have

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `Instant` time.

```
System.out.println(dateTime.plusDays(2).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
```

Comment: Missing test for *"if day is sunday or saturday"*

Comment: I added for how to write same format. Sunday and monday not a problem and totaly i think.

Comment: In all fairness, the asker didn’t seem to ask for this logic, @Andreas. “i know i can add days by using `plusDays`”, not perfect, but not central to the question as I understood it (I was just trying to be kind and provided my version of that logic anyway).

Comment: Your answer is showing all result. My solution is about how to show same format date.