# How to store DateTime at UTC format with Java 8?

Tags: spring-boot, datetime, java-8, date-formatting, iso8601

Spring Boot version `2.3.1`.

I have the following class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CarParkEvent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EventType eventType;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

After storing the event locally I have to send it to the backend.
For now, sending data looks like:

> "createdAt" : "2020-10-01T17:15:23.481"

However, backend expects the following data format:

> "createdAt" : "2020-10-01T17:15:23Z"

The main idea of the application is to **send events to the backend**.
So I need to send exact data which they are expecting.

After looking at the following answers:

- [What is this date format? 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36798830/1498427)
- [How to convert LocalDateTime to `“yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'”` format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526988/1498427)

Could not understand how exactly I have to store this field locally?

Do I need to shift to `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`?

Also, I want to use ***Java 8 Date Time API***.

For controlling date time setting use following utility class:

```
@Slf4j
@UtilityClass
public class TimeClock {

    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public LocalDateTime getCurrentDateTime() {
        return (dateTime == null ? LocalDateTime.now() : dateTime);
    }

    public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime date) {
        log.info("Set current date for application to: {}", date);
        TimeClock.dateTime = date;
    }

    public void resetDateTime() {
        log.info("Reset date for the application");
        TimeClock.dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    /**
     * Different formats for current dateTime.
     */
    public LocalDate getCurrentDate() {
        return getCurrentDateTime().toLocalDate();
    }

    public LocalTime getCurrentTime() {
        return getCurrentDateTime().toLocalTime();
    }
}
```

I use it anywhere where the new date-time should be created.

***What is the best strategy for storing [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) data time format with Java 8 and Spring Boot?***

Comment: Which database  you are using ?

Comment: @Eklavya DB is MySql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `LocalDateTime` here is that it simply doesn't store an offset or a time zone, which means you cannot format it to a `String` that contains a `Z` for UTC respectively an offset of `+00:00`.

I would use a `ZonedDateTime` which will have an offset and a zone id and format is using a specific `DateTimeFormatter` (don't exactly know how your annotation will handle this).

Here's a small plain Java example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get an example time (the current moment) in UTC
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // print its toString (implicitly)
    System.out.println(now);
    // format it using a built-in formatter
    System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
    // or define a formatter yourself and print the ZonedDateTime using that
    System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")));
}
```

The output of this small example was (some seconds ago):

```
2020-10-01T15:06:16.705916600Z
2020-10-01T15:06:16.7059166Z
2020-10-01T15:06:16Z
```

I think you can use such a pattern in the `@JSONFormat` annotation. Not entirely sure, but cannot look it up now.

Comment: what will be prefered way of storing `ZonedDateTime` with JPA at this case?

Comment: @nazar_art some answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840769/how-to-persist-localdate-with-jpa) mentions JPA 2.2 added support for some classes of `java.time` and it has some links. Unfortunately, `ZonedDateTime` seems unsupported.

Comment: looks like it should be supported for this case.